# onload não funciona com setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Estou a horas tentando organizar esse script de acordo com a minha necessidade, a questão é que preciso que o script carregue somente quando toda a pagina carregar e para isso temos o onload.. bom porem quando eu insiro o onload não funciona... outra questão, estou tentando fazer com que apareça o botão curtir do Facebook ao final da contagem que no caso do código irá mostrar o 00 porem gostaria de inserir um iframe tentei também inserir de alguma forma porem sem sucesso. Aproveitando o ensejo se alguém puder me explicar porque a contagem se inicia no 2 ao invés do determinado 3.

Esse é o código que estou trabalhando: https://jsfiddle.net/4mapbkq7/1/

Comment: Mas cadê o onload do seu código? E posta o código aqui mesmo, no próprio editor tem um botão para adicionar código html/css/js e que funciona parecido com o jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse código consegui colocar botão curtir e iframe

```js
 var start = new Date();
 start = Date.parse(start)/1000;
 var seconds = 3; // TEMPO EM SEGUNDOS EM QUE HAVERÁ O REDIRECIONAMENTO
 function CountDown(){
     var now = new Date();
     now = Date.parse(now)/1000;
     var counter = parseInt(seconds-(now-start),10);
     if(counter <= 9){
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = ' 0'+counter;
     }else{
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = counter;
     }
     if(counter > 0){
         timerID = setTimeout("CountDown()", 100)
     }else{
   document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=450&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId" width="450" height="80" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe><br><iframe id="iframe_color_names" name="iframe_color_names" src="http://kithomepage.com/cores/iframe_color_name.php" width="860" height="600" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
  }
 }
 window.setTimeout('CountDown()',100);
```

```html
<span id="countdown">3</span>
```